# Task scheduler run my python script but it does nothing

Tags: python, task, scheduled-tasks, windows-server, windows-task-scheduler

I have a windows server 2012, where I need to move some `.hash` file from one directory to another one.

I build a simple python script that runs well when I launch it manually, the files are all moved.

Now I need to schedule windows for run it every 5 minutes. Task scheduler schedule it, and every 5 minutes execute it, but simply the files are no more moved, even if Task Schedule says it runned successfully.

I googled a lot of similar question, trying to fill the `start in` field, build a `.cmd` script and other things like that, none of these worked.

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out later that there was something wrong with admin's permissions.

With the correct user now all works fine.